# Firebase Update Method Official Example / push().key as Variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I noticed the example uses the newPostKey from the `.push` method *but*, not nested within a `.then` and without a callback.  In the [posted example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data), how does `.update` know to wait for the promise to resolve that newPostKey?  Does `.update` know a variable is a promise? In other words, I do it like below.  Whereas they do it as below below:

```
var postData = {
  "name": supplyNameInput.value,
  "description": supplyDescriptionInput.value,
  "type": doc.querySelector('input[name = "supply-type"]:checked').value,
  "imageURL": clock.now,
  "last modified": clock.now,
  "author": uid
};
var newSupply = suppliesRef.push(postData, function(error) {
  if (error){
    //error
  } else {
    //succesfull
  }
}).then((snap) => {
  suppliesRef.child(snap.key).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    // The Promise was fulfilled
    console.log(snap.key);
    //Now I have generated newKey as snap.key
  }, function(error) {
    // The Promise was rejected.
    console.error(error);
  });
});
```

Official Example.

> ```
> function writeNewPost(uid, username, picture, title, body) {
>   // A post entry.
>   var postData = {
>     author: username,
>     uid: uid,
>     body: body,
>     title: title,
>     starCount: 0,
>     authorPic: picture
>   };
>
>   // Get a key for a new Post.
>   var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('posts').push().key;
>
>   // Write the new post's data simultaneously in the posts list and the user's post list.
>   var updates = {};
>   updates['/posts/' + newPostKey] = postData;
>   updates['/user-posts/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;
>
>   return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `push()` method (when called without any parameters, as it is in the example you shared from the Firebase documentation) is a client-side operation. No round-trip to the server is needed, since it generates a key that is statistically guaranteed to be unique in the client.